Edit feature without losing GPS data in QField
I use QField to collect data entered manually in the field. But also internal GNSS data (horizontal and vertical precision).
In the QGIS form I save the default values: @gnss_horizontal_accuracy and @gnss_vertical_accuracy by checking "Apply default value on update".
In QField:

When I create a point, no problem I recover the precision data;
When I move a point, no problem I recover the precision data;
When I update the data without moving the point then I lose the precision data.

I tried to put constraints like @gnss_horizontal_accuracy IS NOT NULL or @gnss_horizontal_accuracy > 0, but that doesn't change anything.
If I uncheck "Apply default value on update" then I do not retrieve the precision data when I move a point.
I'm getting to the end of my ideas so if you have any new ones I'm interested.
